# Excel INDIRECT syntax inside SUMIF and COUNTIF

Tags: excel

Could you please help me out with these formula bars? I want to replace `'I1'` with `INDIRECT(Y3&"!C2")`.

1. `='I1'!C2` --> `=INDIRECT(Y3&"!C2")`, managed to do this one :P
2. `=SUMIF('I1'!$C$2:INDEX('I1'!$C:$C,$V$2),B2,'I1'!$E$2:INDEX('I1'!$E:$E,$V$2))`--> ?
3. `=SUMIF('I1'!C$2:INDEX('I1'!$C:$C,$V$2),B2,'I1'!F$2:INDEX('I1'!$F:$F,$V$2))` --> ?
4. `=COUNTIF('I1'!$C$2:INDEX('I1'!$C:$C,$V$2),B2)` --> ?

Sorry, but many times I find it hard to keep up with the excel syntax. It gets really complicated. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `=SUMIF(INDIRECT(Y3&"!C2"):INDEX(INDIRECT(Y3&"!$C:$C"),$V$2),B2,INDIRECT(Y3&"!$E$2"):INDEX(INDIRECT(Y3&"!$E:$E"),$V$2))`

2.
`=SUMIF(INDIRECT(Y3&"!C$2"):INDEX(INDIRECT(Y3&"!$C:$C"),$V$2),B2,INDIRECT(Y3&"!F$2"):INDEX(INDIRECT(Y3&"!$F:$F"),$V$2))`

3. `=COUNTIF(Y3&"!C$2":INDEX(INDIRECT(Y3&"!$C:$C"),$V$2),B2)`
   `

Comment: No 2 is working, No3 had a minimal prob with 'I1'  which I solved. No1 seems to not be working due to some syntax error. Could you please check if you can find it? Thanks for the answer!!!

Comment: 1. is working now. But I just realized a problem. When I drag down my cells, C2 won't change to C3. Any ideas how can I solve this? Thanks!!!

Comment: Solved it! =INDIRECT("'"&$Y$3&"'!"&CELL("address",C2))